# Issue with Setting Orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation

There is My ViewController "MyViewControllA" which support both Orientation Landscape and Portrait . And my ViewController "MyViewControllB" supports only Portrait Mode .And I am Pushing "MyViewControllB" on "MyViewControllA"  Now it Works fine when  "MyViewControllA" is in Portrait Mode . But When  "MyViewControllA" is in Lanscape mode The UI of "MyViewControllB" gets Distorted .

```
I am Using these two methods in "MyViewControllB" for Orientation
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
Please correct me where I am wrong???

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an NavigationController you have to implement something like that:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

So the function call in every ViewController is visible.

Answer (score 0):

How the orientation is decided using containers controller basically depends on your view controllers hierarchy.

If I remember well the navigation controller supports only the orientation that is common to all your view controllers. To override this behavior you can subclass the UINavigationController class or (better) use its [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

```
navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:
navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:
```